# XPath return first <a></a> tags within a XHTML file

Tags: xpath, xhtml

I'm new to xpath and don't know much about it. I know that there's a way to find particular tags within xml / xhtml files using xpath. In my case I'm trying to find the first (a) link element. Unfortunately my xpath String [//a[1]/text()] returns all (a) link tags **not the first one**

```
XPATH: //a[1]/text()

Text='Fachliche Expertise'
Text='Zielerreichung'
Text='Gesamtbeurteilung Leistung'

Expected:

Text='Fachliche Expertise'
```

This is the xhtml code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active null" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#group2">Fachliche Expertise</a>
    </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link  null" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#group1">Zielerreichung</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">           
        <a class="nav-link  null" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#group7">Gesamtbeurteilung Leistung</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following XPath expression:

```
/ul/li[1]/a/text()
```

Since the structure of your HTML seems known, we can navigate to the first `<li>` element, and then select the text from the anchor tag.

Comment: This answer is technically correct (+1) but [a more general XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48097901/290085) would be more robust and cover any document structure.

Answer (score 2):

### Problems with other answers provided

- `/ul/li[1]/a/text()` is technically correct but not general – it is particular to the given XHTML structure and
  won't provide *first `<a></a>` tags within a XHTML file* per the
  title request.
- `//a/text()[1]` is just wrong.  It will select the first text nodes
  among all `a` elements.

### Correct answer

This XPath,

```
(//a)[1]
```

will select the first `a` element in the document, regardless of structure.  Then the text node children can be selected via this XPath,

```
(//a)[1]/text()
```

Comment: OK, but perhaps the OP intended to find the first `<a>` tag with respect to its position in the HTML structure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Right, I acknowledged that your XPath is fine for the given XHTML structure, but innumerable variations (such as wrapping the first `a` in a `span`) would cause your XPath to fail whereas `(//a)[1]` will always meet the request for the first `a` regardless of structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Xpath:

```
//a/text()[1]
```

This will select first node only.

Comment: -1: This answer is wrong, and whoever upvoted wasn't paying attention.  `//a/text()[1]` will select the first text nodes among all `a` elements.

Comment: In other words, it selects `Fachliche Expertise`, `Zielerreichung`, and `Gesamtbeurteilung Leistung`.